# Rails 4.1 with pg 0.17.1 -- can't modify fields in model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm working in rails 4.1 with a postgres backend, handled by the 'pg' gem (0.17.1). When I try to update and save some plain integer/string fields, the change *seems* to be successful but doesn't get written to the DB. No errors are thrown anywhere (that I've found).

A schema excerpt can be found below:

```
enable_extension "plpgsql"
create_table "widgets", force: true do |t|
  t.string  "id"
  t.integer  "recipient"
  t.datetime "receivedAt"
end
```

In the rails console:

```
w = Widget.find('14b13b1e')
 => #<Widget id: "14b13b1e", receivedAt: nil, created_at: "2014-10-04 17:10:39", updated_at: "2014-10-04 17:10:39"> 

w.receivedAt = Time.now()
 => 2014-10-04 19:39:33 +0100 
w.save()
 => # database commit runs and returns 'true'

Widget.find('14b13b1e')
 => #<Widget id: "14b13b1e", receivedAt: nil, created_at: "2014-10-04 17:10:39", updated_at: "2014-10-04 17:10:39">
```

I've also tried this using Widget.update, Widget.update_attribute(), and Widget.receivedAt_will_change!(). In every case, I get the same result. There are no errors to be seen:

```
w.errors.messages
=> {}
```

This is happening with all fields that I try to change.

Where else can I look to find the error?

Edit: sorry, I edited down the randIDs because it was a lot of useless text, and forgot to edit one occurrence. Fixed.

I also forgot to mention that I'm using a nonstandard primary key. In my Widgets model, I have

```
self.primary_key = "randID"
```

Widgets still have a normal 'id' field, but it can only be accessed with Widget['id'] (because Widget.id now returns the randID). I haven't had any problems with selecting Widgets.

Comment: Why is the `id` changing? You're looking for `'14b13b1e'` but getting `'14b13b1e4db5c9cb58bdb26157bee89be6ae494a'`. What does your `Widget` class look like?

Comment: Sorry; edited the question to clarify: I was simply deleting some of the string to simplify for the question, and forgot to clip the last occurrence. Fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh. It's totally my fault. Here's an excerpt from my model file, widget.rb

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = "randID"
    before_save :set_randID
    belongs_to :user

    ...
end
```

I was running a function to calculate the primary key (set_randID) BEFORE SAVE (instead of just once before_create, as I should have done). When I was trying to update an instance of the model, the save would try to recalculate and set the primary key on the instance object.

This seems to have failed silently all the way up the stack. The SQL query looks like it returned "true" and the ActiveRecord object had an empty errors hash.

So, issue is fixed; totally my fault, sorry for wasting your time...but does anyone have an idea where I could have looked to notice this earlier?

Comment: Someone probably would have noticed your `before_save` if you included your model code (or at least the relation and callback setup parts of it).